# Running secure (https) seq ACI

Tags: docker, https, azure-container-instances

My Docker seq container exposes both http and https. However, when I deploy it to azure (ACI) it exposes only http.

I tried to create a gateway but the backend pool is not healthy and i cannot fix it.

How can I expose my seq container on https

Answer (score 0):

Azure Container Instances (ACI) reserves the following ports for service functionality:

> 22, 443, 1025-1027, 3389-3399, 9999, 19000, 19080, 19390, 19100,
> 20000-30000, 49152-65534

You need to run https on a different port other than 443.

More information here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting